# I am facing "error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing Pre-Build Event..."

Tags: windows, svn, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I am using visual studio 2005 to build a existing wince project.I am facing the error log 
mentioned below.Can anyone explain what happens here?

**Command Lines**

Creating temporary file "c:\MM pc build\app latest\Dubhe_Main_App\EVM3530_SDK (ARMV4I)\Debug\BAT00000743565380.bat" with contents
[
@echo off

SubWCRev.exe "c:\MM pc build\app latest\Dubhe_Main_App." "c:\MM pc build\app latest\Dubhe_Main_App\SVNVersion.tmpl" "c:\MM pc build\app latest\Dubhe_Main_App\INC\SVNVersion.h"

if errorlevel 1 goto VCReportError

goto VCEnd

:VCReportError

echo Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing Pre-Build Event..."

exit 1

:VCEnd
]
Creating command line """c:\MM pc build\app latest\Dubhe_Main_App\EVM3530_SDK (ARMV4I)\Debug\BAT00000743565380.bat"""

**Output Window**

Performing Pre-Build Event...
SubWCRev : E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at
'C:\MM pc build\app latest' (format 31).
You need to get a newer Subversion client. For more details, see
  http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change
Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing Pre-Build Event..."

Answer (score 0):

Please, read the error message. It says

> E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at
>   'C:\MM pc build\app latest' (format 31). You need to get a newer
>   Subversion client. For more details, see
>   http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change

This working copy (`C:\MM pc build\app latest`) was created by a newer Subversion client version. However, your build seems to be running a very old SVN client version that does not support format of this working copy. Consider upgrading the client to Subversion 1.10 or later.

Comment: thank you for your answer, Let me try that . I am a newbie to wince and SVN. May I know what is the relation between SVN and Wince build system.I hope SVN is to be a version control system like git.Does Visual studio's build depend on SVN's meta files ? I believe both are independent.Correct me if I am wrong.